# Архивация бэкап файла

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как архивировать созданный бэкап файл в SQL SERVER 2008 чрез агент Sql server? надо команду создать

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "архивировать"? Чем стандартные архиваторы не подходят, типа 7zip?

Comment: Через RaR надо . Главное чтоб архивировал созданный бэкап. потом создал файл.rar

Comment: http://axmara.narod.ru/Programs/WinRAR/do_rar/Kak_sdelat_arhiv_rar.html

Comment: Вы используете SQL-агент? Тогда воспользуйтесь процедурой запускающей командную строку, только её надо разрешить. Либо разрешите ActiveX и запустите через Shell.

Comment: Необходимо создать новый шаг в SQL Аgent и выбрать PowerShell или Operating System(CmdExec). Затем написать список команд для архивации полученного файла после шага backup, используя установленный на сервере архиватор.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ну скрипт бакапа вы, я полагаю, можете сделать. Следующим шагом сделайте такой скрипт (все файлы с расширением bak упаковывает в архив rar):

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(500), @strcmd nvarchar(500), @strrar nvarchar(60), @Path nvarchar(1024), @Exp nvarchar(8)
SET @Path = N'' d:\Backup\''
SET @Exp = N''*.bak''
SET @strrar = @Path+''Backup_'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GETDATE(), 5)/*dd-mm-yy*/ + ''.rar''
SET @str = @Path+@Exp
SET @strcmd = ''"C:\progra~1\winrar\rar.exe " a -ep -df'' + @strrar + @str
--архивирование бакапа
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @strcmd
--удаление бэкапа
SET @strcmd = ''del '' + @str
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @strcmd
```